# SQL statement, OleDbException error INSERT

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ms-access

There is no error in the code, but no information is appearing in the database.

```
        string mysql;
        mysql = "INSERT INTO Cars(Make,Model,Price,[Image]) VALUES ('"
        + tbMake.Text + "','" + tbModel.Text + "'," + tbPrice.Text + ",'" +         FileUpload1.FileName + "')";
        siteDB.InsertCommand = mysql;
        DataList1.DataBind();
```

Cheers.

Comment: Well the first problem is that you're trying to embed the values directly into your SQL rather than using parameterized SQL. Fix *that* first, then see whether it helps. (It will fix issues to do with quotes within the data, for example.)

Comment: To add something to Jon Skeet's statement: This also minimizes the risk of SQL injection.

Comment: Why are you using the SelectCommand in with an insert statement?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Not idea what you're on about, it's not going live so security isn't an issue. Using Access database.

Comment: Changed SelectCommand to InsertCommand. No errors anymore, but no new information in my database.

Comment: @ChristopherDunne - How about you try the suggestion before you dismiss it? As for the reason there is no information being put into your database there is likely an error in your query? What debugging steps have you taken?  **I guarantee if you took Jon's suggestion the query would work**

Comment: As I just said, there is no longer an error, but no information appearing in my database. Thank you for your input though.

Comment: @ChristopherDunne - Feel free to update the question and flag the out of date comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an Access database the word IMAGE is a reserved keyword.
If you want to use it you need to encapsulate with square brakets

```
"INSERT INTO Cars(Make,Model,Price,[Image]) VALUES ......"
```

This will resolve you immediate problem, but as John Skeet pointed out in its comment you need to use a parametrized query because this solves also the problem of proper formatting of your text values.

What happens to your handy crafted query if a model name (or make) contains a single quote?
Another syntax error is waiting for you (and from my experience it will bite you just when you have finished to code and are ready to work)

Just to complete the answer, feel free to test if in this way it adds the record to your db

```
 mysql = "INSERT INTO Cars(Make,Model,Price,[Image]) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(mysql, con);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", tbMake.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", tbModel.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", Convert.ToDecimal(tbPrice.Text));  
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", FileUpload1.FileName);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Added this to the code, no errors but still not appearing in my database.

Comment: A side note. OleDb doesn't recognize the parameter by their name. So there is no need to put a name in the parameter placeholders. The conventional way for OleDb is the ? character. However, Access treats everything that it doesn't recognize as a parameter, so it works also if you use @p1...., but please stick to the conventional way to place the parameters placeholders for OleDb

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'OleDbCommand' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Add `using System.Data.OleDb;` at the top of your file.cs

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery(); has not been initialized?

Sorry for all this, I'm really trying to get my head around it. Appreciate the help.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery is a method. Do you initialize and open the connection?

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

I just have using System.Data.OleDb; and beginning of code OleDbConnect con = new OleDbConnection();

Comment: Sorry, but I have little context from your question. The connection should be initialized and opened when you execute these lines of code. Perhaps if add more of your code around the lines I can help you on the opening and closing the connection.

Comment: I've done it now, your input really helped aswell, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming siteDB is an `SQLDataAdapter`.
In this case your code should at least be changed to this:

```
string mysql;
        mysql = "INSERT INTO Cars(Make,Model,Price,Image) VALUES ('"
        + tbMake.Text + "','" + tbModel.Text + "'," + tbPrice.Text + ",'" +         FileUpload1.FileName + "')";
        siteDB.InsertCommand = mysql;
        DataList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: This appears to be exactly the same my friend, thank you though.

Comment: last time I checked, there was siteDB.SelectCommand = xxx. Nevermind